# C++ create vector from template iterators

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

I have a function that takes as an input some template iterators:

```
template<class Iterator, class Comparator>
void Merge(Iterator first, Iterator middle, Iterator last, Comparator cmp) {
```

within it I need to create a temporary vector to store values from where `first` points to where `middle` points.

Is there a way to do this? I tried something like

```
vector<Iterator> temp(first, middle);
```

And I don't get vector of proper type.

Example code:

```
#include <vector>

template<class Iterator>
void Merge(Iterator first, Iterator middle) {
    std::vector<Iterator> temp(first, middle);
    Iterator left_it = temp.begin();
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> myVec = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    Merge(myVec.begin(), myVec.end());
    return 0;
}
```

`example.cpp:6:35: error: conversion from ‘std::vector<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, std::allocator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> > > >::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >*, std::vector<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, std::allocator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> > > > >}’ to non-scalar type ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >’ requested`

Comment: *How* is it "not working"? Do you get build errors (what errors then)? Do you get run-time errors? Unexpected behaviors? And how do you *use* the function, what are the template arguments expanded to? Please  create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: sorry, added an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a vector of the value type of the iterator, not a vector of iterators. You can get the value type using [`std::iterator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) from the `<iterator>` header.

```
typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type value_type;
std::vector<value_type> temp(first, middle);
```